# creating more then one route in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

i am trying to create routes in asp.net mvc

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Localization", // Route name
        "{Culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { Culture = "en-US", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"} // Parameter defaults
    );
```

concept is simple...
controller should be able to called through en-us/Controller/Action or controller/action...
is it possible?

Comment: your solution should work... any problem with it?

Comment: Yes it's only going for route which ever is registered ist...

Comment: try this: add Default on top of Localization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Route constraints

You will have to use a route constraint on the first route that will define how culture string should be formed. Try this route definition instead:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Localization",
    "{Culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { Culture = "en-US", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { Culture = @"\w{2}(?:-\w{2})?" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Route constraint regular expression is not completely correct, because as much as I can recall there are cultures with three-letter codes. Regular expression that I've defined allows for general cultures as well like:

```
/en/Controller
```

or

```
/en-US/Controller
/en-UK/Controller
```

Adjust to your liking.

Comment: a question though can i add a constrait for ajax calls only?

Comment: @Usman: Basically you can yes. But you will have to write your own custom route constraint class that must implement `IRouteConstraint` interface. And since you get `HttpContext` in it, you could obtain information whether request is Ajax or not.